# Distributed OSGi: Read timed out

Tags: osgi, distributed, socket-timeout-exception

I am building a distributed application using Distributed OSGi and Zookeeper. The application should run on Felix and Equinox. I register my services as JAX-WS webservices using `BundleContext.registerService(...)` and query them with a `ServiceTracker<S,T>`. So all service handling is done by the OSGi framework. Each service call does some calculations so it takes some time before responding to the caller.

The problem is that I get `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` exceptions when the service call takes more than 60 seconds. So it seems that there is a default timeout of 60 seconds. Does anybody know how I can configure the timeout that is used by the OSGi framework?

This is the full stack trace:

```
Feb 06, 2012 11:27:02 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://test.com/}LB#{http://test.com/}createSession has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:487)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:68)
    at $Proxy34.createSession(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.dsw.handlers.ServiceInvocationHandler$1.run(ServiceInvocationHandler.java:65)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.dsw.handlers.ServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(ServiceInvocationHandler.java:63)
    at $Proxy34.createSession(Unknown Source)
    at test.Consumer$LoadGeneratingThread.run(Consumer.java:122)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking http://192.168.0.15:9090/LB: Read timed out
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:2058)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:2043)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:639)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:641)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:589)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1319)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2165)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:2134)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1988)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: For others: I got an answer from the mailing list telling me that the timeout is not yet configurable in Apache CXF. The only possibility could be to use a custom CXF interceptor, which is supported in version 1.3, and use this to change the HTTPConduit for each request. I did not try that so far since I discovered more issues with CXF, so I cannot tell you if it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I solved this problem. I'm using cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution-1.2.jar
>       Open the file /META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml and add some content:

```
xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xsi:schemaLocation="......
http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd"

<http-conf:conduit name="*.conduit">   
    <http-conf:client ConnectionTimeout="10000" ReceiveTimeout="20000"/>  
</http-conf:conduit>
```

> That's ok now!